# Task Manager does not show memory usage

Tags: windows-7, task-manager

Using Windows 7 the Task Manager does not show memory usage. I selected different memory columns, none of them worked, and I've tried showing processes from all users. It doesn't slow down my computer.

I can't post a picture but it's like this: only shows K, without actual number of memory usage.

---

```
Image Name--------User Name----CPU----Memory (Private Working Set)------Description
___________________________________________________________________________________________
System -----------SYSTEM ------01-------------------------------K-------NT Kernel &system
___________________________________________________________________________________________
Smss.exe--------- SYSTEM -----00-------------------------------K-------Win Session Manager
___________________________________________________________________________________________
Wininit.exe------ SYSTEM ------00-------------------------------K-------Win Start-up Applic
___________________________________________________________________________________________
```

It's pretty much the same as [this thread](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/56891-my-task-manager-doesnt-show-ram-usage-each-program.html) I found on Google.

Comment: Are you using any funky International settings on your computer?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/189361/how-to-fix-task-manager-memory-column-if-it-shows-lies that question was about when task manager showing ridiculously small memory usage. I just have the exact problem as you (nothing show up), and it fixed the problem for me

Comment: Please accept an answer! Andi's worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. 
All that I had to do is:

1. Open Control Panel
2. Click Change keyboard or other input methods
3. Click Formats tab on top
4. Click Customize Formats/Additional Settings
5. Click Reset
6. Click Apply then OK
7. Restart Computer

Now after restart try opening Task Manager and see if helped. This resetting solved the exact same problem for me.

Comment: This worked for me without evenr restarting windows. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Open Task Manager

Go to processes Tab

View -> Select Colums

Select Memory

Comment: It's not the memory columns that i cannot see, but the actual memory usage.

Answer (score 3):

It's from regional settings. I had Romanian, after installing something it no longer showed the amount, just K; I switched to English (US), it worked; I switched then back to Romanian and it is still working.

Comment: Indeed, changing to English and back to my nativ lenguage solves the issue. Thanks!

Comment: This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Process Explorer tool. It's a separate download, but it's free from Microsoft. It shows you basically every statistic and performance number available, many more details than the built in Task Maanager.

Comment: Thank you Davr, Just wondering do you know what causes this problem? Could it be something serious?

Comment: Process Explorer suffers the exact same problem. Switching back & forth the regional settings seems to fix it too.

Answer (score 0):

I also like [DTaskManager](http://dimio.altervista.org/eng/) for this and in general, as an improvement of regular task manager.