# How can I fix Windows 10 shows the wrong ram values in the details panel of task manager?

Tags: windows-10, memory

For some reason task manager is showing the following values:
[image]

I downloaded RamMap to check if that said different, but it didn't:
[image]

For reference, I have 24 GB of RAM:
[image]

The proccesses tab reports the correct values:
[image]

How can this be fixed without reinstalling Windows as it used to display larger values such as for example `500000 k` for UeEditor.exe.

This is how it is supposed to look(random image of a completely fine task manager):
[image]

Also, why when I sort memory either descending or ascending does it not display in the selected order?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything that needs fixing.

Comment: Same problem here, even updating win10 keeps displaying wrong memory usage values. Idk when microsoft will fix this critical problem.

Comment: Is the problem critical? What errors or problems result from this issue?

Comment: @harrymc Check again, the values of the correct task manager memory values are at the bottom image.

Comment: This should have been closed as a duplicate, if any https://superuser.com/questions/189361/how-to-fix-task-manager-memory-column-if-it-shows-lies