Task manager shows ridiculously wrong memory consumed by processes
After one of windows updates Task Manager in Windows 11 shows memory consumed by processes in its Details tab as single kilobytes which is obviously wrong. Look at the screenshot, it shows Visual Studio with a heavy solution loaded:

Clearly this information is wrong, before it was showing +- a gigabyte.
I asked Microsoft about this but the advice was pretty unspecific: to check windows image health (done, it is ok), and, if it doesn't help, to reinstall Windows. But reinstallation of otherwise perfectly working system with a lot of software installed takes a lot of time, I'd strongly prefer to avoid it.
I use the latest stable version of Windows:

But is started earlier.
Does anyone know what it could be?

Compare the results with another Windows tool that is more competent, such Sysinternals (Microsoft) Process Explotrer, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer . Yes, others have stated here there are issues with Windows 11 Task Manager, too, and this site cannot fix issues with MS code.

I tried with process explorer and I'm surprised. It also shows kilobyte values. Just the same task manager shows. I wonder if it is some kind of a system settings or if I misinterpret what I see.

Look at other rows. devenv.exe likely spawns a slew of other processes, and those are using CPU, GPU, RAM and other resources, while the executable is just a stub.

Check if the sympoms are the same like in this post.
How can I fix Windows 10 shows the wrong ram values in the details panel of task manager?
And check this answer:
https://superuser.com/a/192125/221775
I had the same issue and adjusting the grouping and decimal symbol in regional settings fixed it.

for clarity: the decimal and grouping separators were set to the same character which was fixed by adjusting the mentioned setting

Yes! They were both set to .
It helped, tx!
